# Upserting on Dynamic List in Apex

Tags: apex, upsert

I am trying to upsert a dynamic list of objects into Salesforce using Apex, before point of upsert I have casted a new list to explicitly describe which object this is but I still receive the following error:

> DML on generic List only allowed for insert, update or delete

Code:

```
    String objectName = 'Account'; // this will be dyanmic

    // parse lines
    String csvToParse = attachment.Body.toString();

    List<sObject> dynList = CSVReader.readCSVFile(csvToParse, objectName);

    List<SObject> toUpsert = (List<SObject>)Type.ForName('List<' + objectName  + '>').newInstance();
    toUpsert = dynList;

    // upsert records
    SObjectField extField = Account.Fields.ExtID__c;
    Database.UpsertResult[] up = Database.upsert(toUpsert, extField);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're performing a cast on a value that you then throw away.

```
List<SObject> toUpsert = (List<SObject>)Type.ForName('List<' + objectName  + '>').newInstance();
toUpsert = dynList;
```

When you reassign `toUpsert` to `dynList`, the fact that the previous value of `toUpsert` had a runtime type of `List<someSobjectOrOther>` becomes irrelevant. It has no effect on either the compile-time type of `toUpsert`, which is `List<sObject>`, or the compile-time type of `dynList`, which is also `List<sObject>`, or the runtime type of `dynList`, which appears to also be `List<sObject>` although we cannot see how you're generating that value.

Compile-time types cannot be set dynamically. Runtime types are attributes of values, not of variables. You need to change the runtime type of the actual data here, the *value* you're passing to `Database.upsert()`.

As an example, this code works fine:

```
List<SObject> toUpsert;
String objectName = 'Account';

toUpsert = (List<SObject>)Type.ForName('List<' + objectName  + '>').newInstance();
sObject a = (sObject)Type.forName(objectName).newInstance();
a.put('Name', 'Test');
toUpsert.add(a);

Database.upsert(toUpsert, Account.Id);
```

What matters to `upsert` here is that the underlying values (the Account and the `List<Account>`) have concrete runtime types, even though both values have generic compile-time types. Note that you can reproduce the error you're seeing simply by substituting in

```
toUpsert = (List<SObject>)Type.ForName('List<sObject>').newInstance();
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why any of that is even necessary. I've created a `List<SObject>` and added 5 different SObjects into the list and performed an insert/update/delete (can't upsert but that's easy enough to work around) on it with no issue. What's the value of casting a dynamic list into an SObject list?

Comment: It looks to me like the original poster is doing some kind of data load activity to bring in multiple different objects from CSV data. I see the use case, I'd just rather handle it off-platform myself.